# MySQL: Best way to search in files' content (fulltext search)

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, fulltext-index, inverted-index

I'm currently developing a website which allows the users to upload presentations, documents and e-books (something like scribd and slideshare) so I need to be able to search in the file's content. I'm currently extracting the text from the files in a txt file.
I am considering 2 options as I am using MySQL:

1. Store the plain text in a separate table and use mysql's fulltext index to search through it.
2. Use an inverted index to store words and search through them. (2 new tables - words and many-to-many with the documents table). Now in this case what can I do to work with repeating words that give more relevance to the results.

The text will only be used for searching. The problem with (1) is that the text of an e-book may be huge so I consider limiting it to (for example) 50kb or less.
(2) also has a problem with lots of words in an e-book which, again, can be limited.

So can you guide me to the best way to index the text and be able to do fast fulltext searches. I need to get the best out of mysql in this case.

Comment: Have you considered using Sphinx (http://sphinxsearch.com/about/sphinx/)?  Sounds like it would be a good fit for your problem and technology stack.

Comment: Sounds good, but I also have a tagging system, can I search through both at the same time? I mean, search in tags and text and sort the results based on relevance of the fulltext and the existance of a specific tag.

Also, can I give Sphinx the whole text (some txt files exceed 200kb in size)? Would this be a problem for Sphinx to handle and what is the performance tradeoff in this case? I mean, is it worth it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use Sphinx as suggested by Rob Di Marco. Turns out it is the fastest (and opensource) FullText search engine out there. I had some trouble with compiling and getting SphinxSE not to crash mysql so I now use MariaDB which includes the plugin.

I chose version 1.10 because of the RealTime index. It means that there is no need to wait for the indexer thing to rebuild the entire index if you just add a row. ( I know about the main+delta workarounds but this is way easier to configure and use with SphinxQL )

See also [Some questions related to SphinxSE and RT indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956942/some-questions-related-to-sphinxse-and-rt-indexes)